# zsh completion script with globbing

Tags: shell, zsh, zsh-completion

1. I'd like to write a zsh-completion script, which completes with files in a directory different from the current working directory. (I can archieve this, see below.)
2. Additionally the user shall be able to use globbing on the completed command. **How to archieve this?**

Example:

Let's assume we want to complete a command called `rumple`. `rumple` takes a list of files from `~/rumple` as argument (possibly nested directories/files). A valid invocation may be:

`rumple pumple romple/pample`

Which means `rumple` shall effectively work on `~/rumple/pumple` and `~/rumple/romple/pample`.

Now the zsh-completion script `_rumple` for rumple could look like:

```
#compdef rumple

_path_files -W ~/rumple
```

This completes the first part of the task: `rumple p<TAB>` will complete to `rumple pumple` (assuming there are not other files in ~/rumple starting with 'p'). However the second part is not working. `rumple **/p*` should complete to `rumple  pumple romple/pample`, even if the current working directory is not `~/rumple`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would leave it to the user to configure this sort of behaviour via the `_match` completer or `glob_complete` option.

But you can force it to some extent as follows:

```
#compdef rumple
local a=( ~/rumple/**/* )
compstate[pattern_match]='*'
compadd ${a#$HOME/rumple/}
```

Comment: I will have a look into it. Seems like I need to learn some more about zsh-completion first.

Comment: Hm, I tried your example, but it doesn't work. But I will have a look into _match and glob_complete also.